# Adding my 3 list items to just 1 list<> item

Tags: c#

So, I have a list in my code. I'm wondering if I can add all 3 list to 1 list and keep the same operators/names.

I've tried adding it and then a comma after brackets. I tried adding a new list to it. I've searched google/stack/MSDN/ and the VS forums and found nothing to this particular problem.

```
         fill.complexParameters = new QryGroup()
                {
                    type = "group",
                    logicalOperator = "AND",
                    children = new List<child>
                            {
                            new child
                                {
                                type = "filter",
                                name = "Dish",
                                comparisonOperator = "=",
                                value1 = "PROJ_Dish"
                                }
                            },
                    children1 = new List<child>
                            {
                             new child
                                 {
                                     type = "filter",
                                     name = "PERIOD",
                                     comparisonOperator = "=",
                                     value1 = "PD_NO"
                                 }
                             },
                    children2 = new List<child>
                    {
                        new child
                        {
                            type = "filter",
                            name = "SUB_PERIOD_NO",
                            comparisonOperator = "=",
                            value1 = "PROJ_SUB_PD_NO"
                        }
                    }
                };
```

I'm hoping that I could do something like this, but can't figure out how. I feel like I'm over thinking this. Not even sure if it can be done this way. Any help would be appreciated!

```
                          children = new List<child>
                            new child
                                {
                                  type = "filter",
                                  name = "FISCAL_YEAR",
                                  comparisonOperator = "=",
                                  value1 = "PROJ_FY_CD"
                                }
                                {
                                  type = "filter",
                                  name = "PERIOD_NO",
                                  comparisonOperator = "=",
                                  value1 = "PROJ_PD_NO"
                                }
                                {
                                  type = "filter",
                                  name = "SUB_PERIOD_NO",
                                  comparisonOperator = "=",
                                  value1 = "PROJ_SUB_PD_NO"
                                }
```

Comment: Are you looking for AddRange method of List??

Comment: `var children = new []{ new child(), new child() };` that's one option, if you want a list then add `ToList()` to the end...

Comment: Wow, so many down voters. and incorrect comments. Interesting indeed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entierly sure what your question is, but I think this answers it:

```cs
children = new List<child>()
{
    new child()
    {
        type = "filter",
        name = "FISCAL_YEAR",
        comparisonOperator = "=",
        value1 = "PROJ_FY_CD"
    },
    new child()
    {
        type = "filter",
        name = "PERIOD_NO",
        comparisonOperator = "=",
        value1 = "PROJ_PD_NO"
    },
    new child()
    {
        type = "filter",
        name = "SUB_PERIOD_NO",
        comparisonOperator = "=",
        value1 = "PROJ_SUB_PD_NO"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This works and gets the data we need.

Comment: @Airizzo If this is the correct answer, please accept it by pressing the check mark under the up and downvote buttons

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your class looks something like this

```
class child
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string comparisonOperator { get; set; }
    public string value1 { get; set; }
}
```

You should be able to instantiate a populated collection like this:

```
var children = new List<child> {
        new child
        {
          type = "filter",
          name = "FISCAL_YEAR",
          comparisonOperator = "=",
          value1 = "PROJ_FY_CD"
        },
        new child
        {
            type = "filter",
            name = "PERIOD_NO",
            comparisonOperator = "=",
            value1 = "PROJ_PD_NO"
        },
        new child
        {
            type = "filter",
            name = "SUB_PERIOD_NO",
            comparisonOperator = "=",
            value1 = "PROJ_SUB_PD_NO"
        },
    };
```

Comment: I tried this and I kept getting a Syntax  Error. But I am going to fiddle with it more to see if I can get it to work that way as I like the formatting of it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

at first sight you are missing () in the list constructor

correct list initialisation
IList intList = new List(){ 10, 20, 30, 40 };

Comment: You can omit the () if you use {} afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it with multiple solutions, but I'll provide you with two of them:

Create the list out of the object and then pass the value to the **property children ** inside of your object

```
List<child> list = new List<child>();
```

> Here you will add items to your list.

```
list.Add(new List<child> { new child {... }, new child { ...} }); 

fill.complexParameters = new QryGroup()
{
  type = "group",
  logicalOperator = "AND",
  children = list
}
```

> Pass the list directlry to te property on the object list you are
>   creating.

```
fill.complexParameters = new QryGroup()
{
  type = "group",
  logicalOperator = "AND",
  children = new List<child> { new child{ }, new child{} }
}
```

On the example above child list was passed directly to the property.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately since I am using this to make a httpwebrequest, in the form of Json data retrieval this can't be done with DataContracts. Thank you for commenting though!